# Can I use jquery selector quote child iframe's global variable？

Tags: iframe, jquery-selectors, global-variables, quotes

I need create a iframe dynamically in my page,when I closed it ,it will be removed from my page.
(In fact it jquery plugin **"[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home)"**)

It always the last iframe.I want quote the page's global variable in the iframe.So I think the `$("iframe:last").globalvariable`  would work.I put it in `$(function(){……})` .However it does not.

I already know frame's id and name ,Can I achieve that through "id" or "name"?

Can I use selector quote child iframe's global variable？Or in this case,how can I achieve that ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the parents perspective:

```
var iFrameValue = $('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.mySpecialFunction();
```

OR

```
var iFrameValue = $('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.myLocalVariable;
```

From the iframe perspective

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myLocalVariable = "hello";

function myLocalFunction () {
    return "hello";
}

</script>
```